# Synchronise/Synchronize MySQL with Mobile JSON/Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, mobile, json

I am building a mobile app (using React-Native and Redux). The data (on the client/mobile) are in Javascript Objects, which can be easily changed to JSON. Although the client data (on the mobile device) is in document (rather than relational) data format, changing it from Javascript objects to a relational database is not an issue.

I need to store (and query) this data to a server. **Cost of the server is on top of my selection criteria.** However, I consider MySQL 5.6 free for me, because I have access to shared hosting, which includes MySQL, for other purposes.

Synchronisation/Synchronization is required. However, it is only needed to cater to the client (mobile device) going offline or losing connection for any reason. There is NO need to cater to multiple devices or multiple users accessing the same data.

**Are there any tools, which can help in synchronising JSON/JS Objects with MySQL?** If not, what are your suggestions for an inexpensive Client-Server DB?

**Requirements Summary:**

1. Low Cost
2. Server Database support for ORing, e.g. where ID in (1, 2, 3)
3. Simple Synchronisation between a single client and the server